# Use SQL Server Management Studio to update code first project

Tags: sql, sql-server, ef-code-first, ssms

I have created a project and added an Entity Data model using Code First from Existing Database.

Now, I like using SSMS (2008) to make changes like adding new columns, tables or changing some of the properties table or column properties.

Is there a way that I can make my changes in SSMS then have the Models and Migrations updated accordingly or once you have selected Code first and created you models are you stuck to only making changes in code and running the add migrations and update database from the package manager?

I also need to make sure when I publish the solution the server version of the database is updated accordingly.

Cheers in advance,
Kevin.

Comment: As far as I know you have to stick to running `add-migration` from the package manager console so as to create our migration files. You can of course have these then produce the Sql script you're looking to run by using the `-script` option.

Comment: Thanks. Why I am asking is there are change I may need to make where I am not sure how to code in C# files but can easily make the change directly into the local database in either SSMS or the Server Explorer in VS. The problem I dont know how or if it's possible to then update the relevant file in the project to be able to use, debug then publish said changes.